# Button not removing itself onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to spawn a button whenever the user highlights text. This button should spawn a pop-up and then remove itself if the user clicks on it. If the user clicks anywhere else, it should just remove itself.

For some reason, clicking on the button will not remove the button (though it will spawn the pop-up). I have to click again to remove it.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var selectionText = selection.toString().trim();

  if (selectionText && selectionText !== "") {
    var rect = selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.textContent = "Button";
    button.style.position = "fixed";
    button.style.top = (rect.top - 50) + "px";
    button.style.left = (rect.left) + "px";
    button.onclick = function() {
      const popup = createPopup(selectionText, rect);
      document.body.appendChild(popup);
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
        var isClickInside = popup.contains(event.target);
        if (!isClickInside) {
          popup.parentNode.removeChild(popup);
          document.removeEventListener("mousedown", arguments.callee);
        }
      });
      button.parentNode.removeChild(button)
    }

    document.body.appendChild(button);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
      var isClickInside = button.contains(event.target);
      if (!isClickInside) {
        button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", arguments.callee);
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
<!-- HTML here -->
```

Comment: Please add some HTML to the demo above so we can see the problem.

Comment: Try `button.remove()`

Comment: Maybe you should `preventDefault()` for click or mousedown events to prevent unwanted handlers to run

Comment: @isherwood This is a chrome extension, the HTML won't really provide more context.

Comment: `arguments.callee` is deprecated. instead use a variable for the function so you can remove it later.

Comment: Default type of a button is `submit`. Set `button.type='button'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the suggestions so far have fixed the issue. It's strange because clicking outside the button will remove it as expected, but clicking the button itself will not remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) can at least make your code clearer. It may also be wise to track te event types, to avoid events getting in each others way.

Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) based on your code. Maybe useful.

```js
document.addEventListener(`mouseup`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`mousedown`, handle);
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  console.clear();
  const targetBttn = evt.target.closest(`[data-created]`);
  const existingBttn = document.querySelector(`[data-created]`);
  
  if (evt.type === `mousedown` && !targetBttn) {
    return existingBttn?.remove();
  }
  
  if (evt.type === `click` && targetBttn) {
    targetBttn.remove()
    return console.log(`this ofcourse should be a popup`);
  }
  
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const selectionText = selection.toString().trim();

  if (selectionText && selectionText !== "" && !existingBttn) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
      `beforeend`, `
      <button data-created="1"><b>Button</b></button>` );
  }
  
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML here -->
<div>yada yada yada</div>

<div>yada 2 yada 2 yada 2</div>
```